# SPARQL with curl

Tags: sparql

I have the query below in a file(Artist.rq) which I use in the following curl-command:

`curl  -H "Accept: application/json" --data-urlencode "query@Artist.rq" "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query="`

But I get the following java-error:

```
 SPARQL-QUERY: queryStr=
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException: Encountered   "<EOF>" at line 1, column 0.
 Was expecting one of:
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "construct" ...
    "describe" ...
    "ask" ...

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    ...
```

My query:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT ?inceptionDate ?logo ?genreLabel ?record_labelLabel ?countryLabel ?cityLabel WHERE {   
  OPTIONAL { wd:Q856941 wdt:P571 ?inceptionDate . }
  OPTIONAL { wd:Q856941 wdt:P154 ?logo . }
  OPTIONAL { wd:Q856941 wdt:P136 ?genre . }
  OPTIONAL { wd:Q856941 wdt:P264 ?record_label . }
  OPTIONAL { wd:Q856941 wdt:P495 ?country . }
  OPTIONAL { wd:Q856941 wdt:P740 ?city . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
}
LIMIT 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `curl  -H "Accept: application/json" -G 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql' --data-urlencode query="$(< Artist.rq)"`

Comment: Worked perfect, thank you!

Comment: The problem is the empty `query` parameter in the URL. Just leave it out: `curl -H "Accept: application/json" --data-urlencode query@Artist.rq https://query.wikidata.org/sparql`.